# What does (:=) mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

- nexts := nexts (step)*
  *nextstep := pop (nexts)* /* How to transform this part ( := ) in Haskell code

Comment: `:=` is not a standard Haskell operator that I'm aware of (or that [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3D) is aware of). Can you provide more context? Are you importing a library?

Comment: Please only use relevant tags in your questions: unless this is from Real World Haskell, you should not include the tag.

Comment: I have a blockCode that should transform in Haskell like this one just a small part..result := backtrack (nextstep, goal, (depth + 1), [step : path]) Idont know what does this operator (:= ) do?!!

Comment: Can you give us more information about where you found `:=` - if you include more of what you read, we might be able to help decipher it.

Answer (score 5):

`(:=)` is actually a constructor. It builds up a datatype. We can't know *what* data type it constructs without knowing what libraries you've imported. But as an example

```
 data Example = String := Int
```

and then we could write

```
 demo = "foo" := 0

 demo2 :: Example -> Int
 demo2 (_ := i) = i
```

In the first `demo` we construct an `Example` using this constructor and in the second we pattern match across it and return the `Int` component.

Comment: ok perfect thanks I got it..I knew that (:)is acostructor but this one ..no idea :=?

Comment: @user3317519 Haskell has pretty simple rules for constructors, all constructors are either infix operators starting with `:=` or start with an uppercase letter. Of course, there has to be some definition of the constructor somewhere but you can always tell a constructor from a function like this

Comment: @jozefg That should be "starting with `:` or an uppercase letter".

Answer (score 3):

Given the context of your deleted question: you have an algorithm in pseudo-code and need to implement it in Haskell. In this case `:=` means "assign" and is written simply `=` in Haskell. Of course, you can't just translate the pseudocode symbol-by-symbol and expect to end up with a Haskell program. E.g. the pseudocode has a loop with mutable variables; you'll have to use recursion instead.

Here is a very simple example:

Pseudocode:

```
i := 0
j := 10

while (i < j)
  i := i + 1
  j := j - 1

return j
```

Haskell:

```
x = let (_, j) = foo 0 10 in j
    where foo i j | i < j = foo (i + 1) (j - 1)
                  | otherwise = (i, j)
```

Comment: thanks can you give me an example of (while) in haskell?

Comment: I've added an example.